# Can I use DRF to create a page based site (e.g. a blog)?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Can I use Django Rest Framework to create an "ordinary" site - like a blog, with templated HTML pages ala "normal" django?

The reason I ask this is that I am building a website (sort of a blog), but for sections of the site, the functionality will be provided by making CALLS to a REST API.

So, my question essentially is this:

Is DRF equivalent to (all the features/functionality of django) + ability to create/use RESTful APIs?

Comment: "Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit for building Web APIs."  - The very first line of the docs...

Comment: @Sayse I never thought to check the documentation first (sarcasm). So how do you propose that a website consisting of templated HTML pages and a RESTful API be built?

Comment: Exactly how you (unintentionally?) say it in your comment, you've separated the front and backend completely. So you find something that supports the front end creation you require. Node, ionic, there is a huge list of options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django Rest Framework is an *add-on* to Django. It doesn't replace Django; it's just another app. You still create your models via Django, and can use views and templates as normal.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to answer the question, and saving me countless hours scanning the documentation, source code, forums etc for the answer. Before I accept your question however, could you please confirm if my understanding is correct - if I wanted to create a blog application (for example), and I wanted parts of the website to consume a REST API, I can create a django application, and add DRF as a third party application to my django app? Any examples of this online?

Comment: Hang on, you're talking about *consuming* a REST API? That has nothing to do with DRF, which is a framework for *generating* an API using your Django models.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the cause of the confusion regarding what I'm doing. The website is django based - I'm building that. However I'm also responsible for creating the REST api consumed by certain pages on the website. My question is that do I need separate installations of dgango and DRF, or can I simply include  DRF as an application in my django application. HTH

Comment: Right, I understand, sorry. Yes you can simply include DRF in your main Django project, no need for two installations; you simply configure the API routes to be served by DRF views and the others by standard Django views.